# Passing custom themes into withStyles

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I have created a theme that I'm trying to call in my useStyles. This is the theme

```
import { createMuiTheme } from "@material-ui/core/styles";

const customTheme = createMuiTheme({
    palette: {
        primary: {
            main: "#00ffff"
        },
        secondary: {
            light: "#214b63",
            main: "#000000",
            dark: "#00660f",
            contrastText: "#fff"
        }
    }
});

export default customTheme;
```

I want to use the secondary color as part of the override:

```
import React from "react";
import { Grid, Typography } from "@material-ui/core";
import { withStyles, MuiThemeProvider } from "@material-ui/core/styles";
import customTheme from "./newTheme";

const useStyles = (theme) => ({
  root: {
    color: theme.palette.secondary.main
  },
  grid: {
    height: "100vh"
  }
});

class CustomThemes extends React.Component {
  render() {
    const { classes } = this.props;

    return (
      <MuiThemeProvider theme={customTheme}>
        <Grid
          className={classes.grid}
          container
          justify="center"
          alignItems="center"
        >
          <Grid item>
            <Typography className={classes.root}>
              Upgraded to withStyles theming problem
            </Typography>
          </Grid>
        </Grid>
      </MuiThemeProvider>
    );
  }
}

export default withStyles(useStyles)(CustomThemes);
```

I'm trying to pass the theme colors into the useStyles, so that the root color can work. Is there any way for me to pass the theme color into my override? I read that there is a way with makeStyles, but all my components are class-based, and converting all of them into hooks would not be possible. I need this because I have a similar component being used at multiple places. It would be convenient to be able to control the color palettes from one place.

I have tried doing it in this manner as well, but this doesn't take in the custom theme.:

```
const useStyles = (customTheme) => ({
  root: {
    color: customTheme.palette.secondary.main
  },
  grid: {
    height: "100vh"
  }
});
```

Another way I've tried is

```
export default withStyles(useStyles, { withTheme: true })(CustomThemes);
```

I have a css injection as well, but wanted to know it can be done this way (what I believe is the native-to-mui way). Appreciate all the help!

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer. Didn't know this, but I can call the theme directly into my useStyles:

```
const useStyles = (theme) => ({
  root: {
    color: customTheme.palette.secondary.main
  },
  grid: {
    height: "100vh"
  }
});
```

If anyone knows why I don't need to inject the theme directly in, would greatly help in understanding why this works. I spent almost 2 days trying to pass the theme in.